# XCode: Using LLVM IR as source code?

Tags: xcode, llvm, llvm-ir

I have an iOS project that contains a few thousand lines of assembly code for 4 different CPU architectures: i386, x86-64, armv7, and arm64.

It would be nice to replace all that target-specific assembly with a single version expressed in LLVM IR. Instead of 4 .S files there'd be one single .ll file going through LLVM's static compiler llc.

Has anyone done anything like this? Can XCode accept LLVM IR as source code?

Comment: If you're going to change all the (possibly) platform-specific code to platform independent LLVM IR code, then why not go a step further and use some higher level language like C, C++ or Swift? And if you have the assembler code for optimization reasons, what make you think that LLVM IR will be equally optimized?

Comment: The assembly code emulates an old CPU and is vastly faster than corresponding C code mainly because it keeps almost all the emulated CPU state in registers. It's not the sort of optimisation a front-end compiler does well, in my experience. And as far as I can tell the IR code looks very similar to target assembler most of the time... I don't need any clever optimisation there, just something to do a simple line-for-line translation (more or less) to the target architecture.

Comment: Well, you'll notice that at the IR level there are infinitely many registers that can be used (in fact it's in SSA form). Register allocation actually happens in the backend that processes the IR. Hence if you don't like the register allocation choices when compiling C code, those same problems will be present if you try to compile the IR too.